# How to Hide Add to cart button in Magento 2 front end without editing phtml file

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, addtocart

I created a custom module which has option to enable / disable Add to cart button in front end , I'm trying to hide button without editing the core templates files , is there any way to implement it .

Also i tried to solve this using Observer function from my module but that's not working exactly as i needed.

Any help is appreciated , Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to override core phtml in your Module

Comment: You have to override addtocart.phtml file

Comment: My requirement is a custom module to implement it all , if i override addtocart then i have to create a folder in current theme and then only it will work , im trying to create as a module which will be plug an play for multiple magento sites.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @fudu no i didn't get solution for this.

Comment: me too, i've follow this so far, but nothing work .. still have to override phtml file